# Redis connection issue

Tags: freebsd, connection, redis, time-wait

We are currently experiencing a lot of Redis errors with the message

> Unable to connect: read error on connection, trying next server

We run Redis on FreeBSD using PHP Redis and we have a hard time reproducing the error on Ubuntu so this might be a hint. There's a long-running [issue on that topic on github](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/issues/70).

Basically we get a socket from the operating system with a call to `connect(host, port, timeout)` in phpredis, but when we do a `select(db_index)` afterwards, we get an exception.
Could there be an issue with persistance? I assume that connect does nothing in the background and select tries to access the connection, which is actually closed.

We don't run into a timeout. We tried tuning TIME_WAIT without success.

Any other ideas on where the problem might come from?
What is the best way to track the issue down? dtrace maybe?

**Update**

We are currently looking into our BGSAVE settings. Interestingly it takes half a second and more to create a fork for the process which regularly writes the data to disk (persistence) and maybe redis can't respond to `connect()` requests during that timespan.

Answer (score 2):

We reduced the error rate by 90% with the following [redis command](http://redis.io/commands/config-set):

```
CONFIG SET save ""
```

This disables BGSAVE, which regulary stores all database changes on disk.
The reason for the connect errors most likely come from a blocking `fork()` operation of the main redis process to start the BGSAVE process.

The redis.conf says:

```
# Redis may block too long on the fsync() call. Note that there is no fix for
# this currently, as even performing fsync in a different thread will block
# our synchronous write(2) call.
```

Also see how the mechanism is implemented with a simple `fork()` [here](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/93e7a130fc9594e41ccfc996b5eca7626ae5356a/src/rdb.c#L718).
We think about using a dedicated redis server from our pool which will be responsible for the BGSAVE operations and just using the others for reading/writing.

From IRC chat, it seems like a couple of other companies ran into the same error. *Bump* was using a master/slave system as well. The slave does not accept connections and is only there to persist the data (see the [discussion on hackernews here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2222431))

*Hulu* says the following:
"To keep performance consistent on the shards, we disabled the writing to disk across all the shards, and we have a cron job that runs at 4am everyday doing a rolling “BGSAVE” command on each individual instance." ([see here](http://blog.gopivotal.com/pivotal/case-studies-2/case-study-how-hulu-scaled-serving-4-billion-videos-using-redis#sthash.z3Yzm54c.dpuf))

**Edit:**

It turns out that this was just a temporary fix. Load increased and we are back at the high error rates. Nevertheless I'm quite confident that a background operation (e.g. a fork, or a short-running background process) is causing the errors as the error messages always appear in blocks.

**Edit2:**

Since Redis is single-threaded, always keep an eye on long-running operations because they block everything else. An example is the `keys *` command. Avoid it and use `scan` instead